# BroadcastReceiver makes app crash when its called

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

My app updates each Tuesday, if the user isn't connected to the internet then the update gets delayed by 24 hours with the method ***setAlarm(-2)***. If the ***data.json*** file doesn't exist then that means it's the user's first time opening the app so it just sets a new alarm to the coming Tuesday and updates the json. All works great when the app is running even in the background it works, no problem, but if the app is not running (closed) when the alarm gets called the app crashes unfortunately.

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static long alarmTime = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    alarmTime = NextTuesday.nextDayOfWeek(Calendar.TUESDAY).getTimeInMillis();

        File file = context.getFileStreamPath("data.json");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "FIRST BOOT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (isConnectedToInternet(context)) {
                UpcomingFragment.getInstance().setAlarm(-1);
                UpcomingFragment.getInstance().update();
            } else {
                //a day from now
                UpcomingFragment.getInstance().setAlarm(-2);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "FILE EXISTS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intentMain = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intentMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intentMain);


            if (isConnectedToInternet(context)) {
                UpcomingFragment.getInstance().setAlarm(-1);
                UpcomingFragment.getInstance().update();
            } else {
                //a day from now
                UpcomingFragment.getInstance().setAlarm(-2);
            }
        }

}

public static long getAlermTimeInMillis(){
    return alarmTime;
}

private boolean isConnectedToInternet(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork= connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return  activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

}

NextTuesday class

```
public class NextTuesday {

public static Calendar nextDayOfWeek(int dow) {
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    int diff = dow - date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if (!(diff > 0)) {
        diff += 7;
    }
    date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, diff);
    return date;
}

public static String dateInString(int day){
    Calendar date = nextDayOfWeek(day);
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dateString = format1.format(date.getTime());
    return dateString;
}
```

}

Fragment's setAlarm()

```
    public void setAlarm(int i){
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), UpdateReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);

    if (i == 0) {
        alarmTime = 0;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Setting alarm for first time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (i == -2) {
        alarmTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+24*60*60*1000; // a day
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NO WIFI RESTARTING AFTER A DAY" + alarmTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        alarmTime = UpdateReceiver.getAlermTimeInMillis();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Setting alarm for next tuesday", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
    // constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

}
```

update()

```
    public void update(){
    // Formulate the request and handle the response.
    try {
        dataList.clear();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "LOADING FROM VOLLEY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e(TAG, "FROM VOLLEY");
                        try {
                            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(getActivity().openFileOutput("data.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
                            outputStreamWriter.write(response.toString());
                            outputStreamWriter.close();
                            sendJsonRequest();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Fetching New Data. Check your Wi-Fi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        //remove cash
        jsonObjectRequest.setShouldCache(false);
        mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Appreciate any kind of help, and no stack-trace gets printed when the app crashes.

Comment: Please post your logcat to identify error

Comment: Without a stacktrace, it's very difficult to help you. I would suggest using the debugger, with exception breakpoints enabled, so you can identify where the app is crashing.

Comment: Do I try and catch any exception in the BrodcastReceiver or in the setAlarm method? Cause in BroadCastReceiver nothing gets caught

Comment: @MikeM I'm guessing same applies to the update() method?

Comment: Yep I just did remove the .getInstance(), can I post my update() method and can you tell me if I could make it static? Because it relies heavily on the activity it is in

Comment: The `sendJsonRequest()` method is pretty easy to make static, and I could definitely make the `update()` method static, but do you have a better idea?

Comment: Anyways thanks for the help @MikeM. Why not post it as an answer, I'll mark it as the best answer, thanks again

Comment: Hey. any idea though, why the intent doesn't work in the BroadcastReceiver though? Because Unfortunately I can't make `update()` static, trust me I tried. So I need to open an instance of UpcomingFragment

Comment: @MikeM I need your help!